# Grails / GORM - equivalent to JPA @ElementCollection

Tags: grails, jpa, annotations, grails-orm

I have a composition pattern where a parent object has a list of child objects, e.g., Order and LineItem.

It behaves similar to cascading with delete orphans, but the child objects are @Embeddables instead of @Entities, and don't get their own IDs - they're always managed through their parent object.

In JPA I could do something like this to ensure that whenever I save an Order, the collection of LineItems synchronize, including deleting removed items:

```
public class Order {
  @ElementCollection
  @CollectionTable(...)

  private Set<LineItem> items;

}
```

In Grails, what's the equivalent?

I can do hasMany with cascade all-delete-orphan but would prefer if there were a similar way for the child objects to not have their own IDs (basically, not be entities).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `static embedded` in `Order`. Refer [this](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/embedded.html).

Comment: That would work for other @Embeddable use cases but doesn't address @ElementCollection/@CollectionTable.

Comment: GORM can provide you the relationship you wanted I guess, if I am not wrong. I scribbled down a use case here(http://pastebin.com/xwd4augW), you can refer that. The objective is to dynamically populate the list of embedded children which the example does. Let know I have misunderstood your question.